# How does java LoginContext.login() work?

Tags: java, authentication, jndi, jaas

I have this code to create a configuration of a java client to connect to a JBoss application server:

```
System.setProperty( "java.security.auth.login.config", "auth.conf" );
LoginContext auth = new LoginContext( "myAuth", 
    new LoginCallbackHandler( username, password ) );
auth.login();
```

The file `auth.conf` contains the following lines:

```
myAuth {
    org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule required;
};
```

Now, somewhere else in the code (the LoginContext `auth` isn't known there) I have an EJB that does a `initialContext.lookup( jndiName )` and a `narrow()` to access a Bean on the JBoss application server. This `narrow` only succeeds if the login information of the first step was correct.

#### Question

How does the login information propagate from the `LoginContext` to the `narrow()`? I don't see any connection between these two places.

And further, how could I do two or more different logins inside of one client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a nice explanation in the [JBoss documentation (chapter 8.4.1)](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r3/html/ch8.chapter.html):

[image: jboss jaas login]

The `login()` call only binds the name and password to the JBoss EJB layer of the client. All subsequent EJB calls will use these credentials and pass them to the called EJB method.

Comment: How Login context is passed to the EJB calls?