# Java EE declarative security, acquiring reference to a secured bean from application client

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, declarative-authorization, declarative-security

On 2 questions I would like to consult you.

**Background**: I have written a test, Java EE application and added declarative security. The application is deployed on Glassfish 3.1. For unit testing I used JUnit with the embedded container for all beans with local interface. For the entry point of the appliaction, the SessionFacde bean, which has the only remote interface, I wrote a simple client which acquires reference to the SessionFace bean. Security annotations I applied for the SessionFacade bean only.

**(Question 1:** What is the recommended unit testing strategy with security? Is it all right if I utilize a simple application client for the sessionFacade? (The other (local) beans are not affected as no security annotations are applied there.))

**Question 2:** How should I access the SessionFacde form the appliaction client? I would really appriciate if you could copy here some code samples for the application-client.xml and acquiring a reference to the JNDI service. This would spare me a lot of time. The question is similar to the one under [Java EE 6 Application Client login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663711/java-ee-6-application-client-login) but I found an explanation (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beacm.html) that it is not really recommended as it loads the burden of security back to the developer instead of the framework. See the below text:

> "[...]Programmatic login allows the application developer to bypass
>   the GlassFish Server-supported authentication mechanisms and feed
>   authentication data directly to the security service. While flexible,
>   this capability should not be used without some understanding of
>   security issues.
>
> Since this mechanism bypasses the container-managed authentication
>   process and sequence, the application developer must be very careful
>   in making sure that authentication is established before accessing any
>   restricted resources or methods. It is also the application
>   developer’s responsibility to verify the status of the login attempt
>   and to alter the behavior of the application accordingly.
>
> The programmatic login state does not necessarily persist in sessions
>   or participate in single sign-on.[...]"

Thank you that you have read it so far.
Kind regards,
Tamas

**Remark:** As there has been no response since I wrote the original post, I would say it would be enough to answer the second question. It would help me to go on. Thanks, Tamas

Comment: **Remark:** As there has been no response since I wrote the original post, I would say it would be enough to answer the second question. It would help me to go on. Thanks, Tamas